# How DbMigrationsConfiguration is related to a DbMigration in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

In Entity Framework by using `Enable-Migrations` a *Migrations* folder is created containing a `Configuration` inherited from `DbMigrationsConfiguration` like this:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
    ...
}
```

All the created migrations which are created using `Add-Migration` are placed in the *Migrations* folder too.

```
public partial class Init: DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        ...
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I didn't find any code that relates these two together ( for example having a configuration property in migrations). The only relation I found is that both are placed in same folder. If I have more than 1 `DbContext` and consequently more than 1 Configuration, I'm wondering how these `DbMigration`s are distinguished?

**Question:** How `DbMigration` classes are related to a `Configuration`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are related by convention. By default, it will store the migrations in a root folder called Migrations. You can override this in the constructor of the config (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrationsconfiguration(v=vs.113).aspx) or when you enable-migrations:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations\Context1";
}
```

For multiple contexts, create a different config and folder for each by using -ContextTypeName ProjectName.Models.Context2 -MigrationsDirectory:Migrations\Context2. Here is a walkthrough: http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/entityframework/entity-framework-6-code-first-migrations-with-multiple-data-contexts

Comment: In addition, it can be useful `MigrationsNamespace` too. E.g. `MigrationsNamespace = this.GetType().Namespace + ".Context1";`

Answer (score -1):

When you run the update-database command, the database operations in the up() method in the latest DbMigration derived classes is performed.  If that is successful, the commands in the Configuration class are executed.  One of those methods is the seed() method where you can optionally add code to plug values into your tables after a migration.  When you specify a target migration (presumably earlier than the latest), the migration works through the chain of down() methods in the migration classes to get to the version you wanted.

Comment: If migration is not added, nothing is added in database then what is the use of update-database???

Comment: The seed() method could add records to the tables. You could also use the update-database command to generate SQL scripts.