# Model backing the Db context has changed but run anyway. Is there a way to turn off migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I want my windows application to warn that there are migrations to run but to give the user the option to continue without running them.

At the moment I have code first projects with no migrations that access the database
However in the project where I do the database migrations I must either allow the migration to run or delete the migration and undo my changes to the model.

For the configuration I have

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

For the migration check I have

```
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
            {
                var compatible = db.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false);
                if (!compatible)
                {
                   compatible= RunMigrations(db);
                }
                return compatible;
            }
```

If I don't allow the migration then I get the model backing error when I try to access data

```
 var n = db.mytable.count()  // will error
```

If I comment out the Configuration class and code that calls it I can run the program without error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267660/how-dbmigrationsconfiguration-is-related-to-a-dbmigration-in-ef

Comment: maybe i need 2 dbcontexts in the same project one for migrations and one not for.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to create a new dbContext inheriting from the usual

```
public class MigrationDbContext : MyDbContext
{
}
```

Then the configuration class should use the MigrationDContext

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MigrationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

and the migration check should use the MigrationDbContext